# Getting error in SQL query using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I'm still learning the MySQl.
This is the relational DBMS :

```
CUSTOMER (CustID, CustName, AnnualRevenue)
TRUCK (TruckNumber, DriverName)
CITY (CityName, Population)
SHIPMENT (ShipmentNumber, CustID, Weight, Year, TruckNumber, CityName)
```

Now, I have to formulate for these two queries:

> 1. Total weight of shipments per year for each city.
> 2. Drivers who drove shipments to London but not Paris.

These are the queries i have came up with:
1.

```
select sum(s.weight), s.year , c.city
from shipment s, city c
INNER JOIN CITY
on s.CityName = c.CityName
```

Comment: Where's your second faulty one?

Comment: You probably need a GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing and old way to JOIN table (which you should avoid because the  joining columns are not explicitly stated and it is confusing for others):

```
FROM shipment s, city c
```

You should group columns in the select that are not aggregated (year, city). Also it is better to use an alias for the aggregated column (AS total_weight)

```
select sum(s.weight) AS total_weight, s.year , c.city
from shipment s
INNER JOIN CITY as c
on s.CityName = c.CityName
GROUP BY s.year, c.city
```

Try to solve the second query and come back if you have a problem.

Comment: select t.DriverName 
from truck t
INNER JOIN Shipment S
on t.TruckNumber = s.TruckNumber
where s.city = 'London' AND NOT s.city = 'Paris'     , Can this be the second query ?

Comment: Not really, remember that the where is evaluated by row, that means that it does not make sense to evaluate the same column with two different values because it can't have two. There are several ways, for example repeat the same query ( almost) to get the drivers that delieverd to Paris, put that as a subquery and then change your query to s.city='London' and t.DriverName NOT IN ( Select DriverName FROM ....)

That way you will get drivers that delievered to Londo but that did not delivered to Paris

Comment: Some help [link](https://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-not-in.htm)